# BigDecimal.divide() yields extra digit of precision when called with a MathContext

Tags: java, bigdecimal, arbitrary-precision, precision

Given the simple program

```
import java.math.*;
import static java.math.BigDecimal.ONE;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuffer ruler = new StringBuffer("  ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         ruler.append("1234567890");
    }

    out.println(ONE.divide(new BigDecimal(47), 50, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
    out.println(ONE.divide(new BigDecimal(47), new MathContext(50, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)));
    out.println(ruler);
    out.println(ONE.divide(new BigDecimal(6), 5, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
    out.println(ONE.divide(new BigDecimal(6), new MathContext(5, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)));
}
```

This is the output:

> ```
> 0.02127659574468085106382978723404255319148936170213
> 0.021276595744680851063829787234042553191489361702128
>   12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
> 0.16667
> 0.16667
> ```

I would expect the second line of output to be the same as the first line.  Is that a bug, or have I misinterpreted the `BigDecimal` documentation?

JVM version:

> ```
> $ java -version
> java version "1.7.0_45"
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have confused *scale* (total number of decimal places) with *precision* (number of significant digits).  For numbers between -1 and 1, the *precision* does not count any zeroes between the decimal point and the non-zero decimal places, but the *scale* does.

The second argument to `BigDecimal.divide` is a *scale*.  So you get 50 decimal places for your first output.

The argument to the `MathContext` constructor is a *precision*.  So for your second output, you get 50 significant decimal places, plus one additional zero between the decimal point and the 2.

```
  First decimal place (start counting scale from here)
  ↓
0.02127659574468085106382978723
   ↑
   First significant digit (start counting precision from here)
```

Comment: Because there are no additional zeroes between the decimal point and the 16667.